# Can I customize "command not found" bash message?

Tags: bash, debian

Title pretty much. I tried editing bash.bashrc, the command not found handle, but it did nothing really. I changed the marked line, for example to "%s:command not found dumbo\n", but nothing changed.[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you tried. We can't know why it didn't work if you don't show us what you did.

Comment: There's not much more to it than just `command_not_found_handle() { echo Whatever; }`. Also, do you mean "~/.bashrc"? It could be you're editing the wrong file. Don't forget to either `source` it or restart your terminal afterwards.

Comment: `command_not_found_handle()` is only available when package `command-not-found` is installed.

Comment: @PauloTomé From the `bash(1)` manpage: "If the search is unsuccessful, the shell  searches for a defined shell function named command_not_found_handle." Also, from the Ubuntu package description for command-not-found: "This package will install a handler for command_not_found that looks up programs not currently installed but available from the repositories." So no.

Comment: @terdon edited it. im dumb for not doing it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the following to .bashrc or to any other file and afterwards source it.

```
command_not_found_handle () {
       printf "%s\n" "i do not speak Klingon";
       return 127
}
```

don't forget to run `source file_you_modified`

Comment: Why would you add a `#!/bin/sh` hashbang to your __bash__ rc file?  Or any rc file for that matter.  Also you should not include formatting in the `printf` message string, and your `;` line break is not needed.

Comment: if you dont format the printf your output will be followed by your shell prompt in the same line. Yes the line break is not needed but it does not hurt.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  Your `printf` command should be:  `printf '%s\n' "I do not speak Klingon"`.  The format string should be its own argument.

Comment: thnaks for the correction, if you'd like to edit the above i'll approve it